# when clicked on a button how event is generated

Tags: java, events, button, awt, actionlistener

I am complete fresher to java GUI.I read a statement in a book that "when we click on the button an event is generated".Is event a class , if yes then its object gets generated when we clicked on the button.Where this event object goes.?I think it first goes to the underlying OS.I am not sure please someone throw some light on it. Or please refer me a  book which covers all these internal aspects.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? I hope it is only out of couriosity because in normal programming it does not matter. Also the answer will depend on the OS used.

Comment: [Oracle - Introduction to Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Is event a class?

No, event is not class, it is interface. For example, by click on `JButton`, `ActionListener` interface is called and it execute abstract method of `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` for that button.

Comment: So, actually the `ActionEvent` (the Event being fired) is a [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html)

Comment: mm little confusing your answer,"interface is called and it execute abstract method"

Comment: ActionEvent is a class,  that gives information about the event of Button.